# Trying to link library to a file which uses OpenGL and linker not being able to find GL relevant file

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

So this is my output when i run

```
$ g++ main.c -lGL 
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

however i DO have GL installed because it came with my graphics card driver which i downloaded from nvidia website namely the 346.72 for my graphics card 780ti

when i do a search i.e locate GL here is part of the response

```
...
/usr/include/GL
/usr/include/GL/freeglut.h
/usr/include/GL/freeglut_ext.h
/usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h
/usr/include/GL/gl.h
/usr/include/GL/gl_mangle.h
/usr/include/GL/glcorearb.h
/usr/include/GL/glew.h
/usr/include/GL/glext.h
/usr/include/GL/glu.h
/usr/include/GL/glu_mangle.h
/usr/include/GL/glut.h
/usr/include/GL/glx.h
/usr/include/GL/glx_mangle.h
/usr/include/GL/glxew.h
/usr/include/GL/glxext.h
/usr/include/GL/glxint.h
/usr/include/GL/glxmd.h
/usr/include/GL/glxproto.h
/usr/include/GL/glxtokens.h
/usr/include/GL/internal
/usr/include/GL/wglew.h
/usr/include/GL/internal/dri_interface.h
/usr/include/GL/internal/glcore.h
...
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.346.72
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.la
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.346.72
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.346.72
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.346.72
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5.2.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4.8.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
....
```

which shows that it does exist

how do i link this with the linker?

Comment: The include folder only holds header files, not (static/shared) libraries, which is what you need to solve this error. Try setting up the library path to your the folder which holds the OpenGL libs (probably /usr/libs/GL).

Comment: _@hop joppe5_ Please add the information that you are using `$ g++ main.c -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lGL` to your question. I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way is to add the directory containing architecture-plattform specific libraries, like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to the system linker path. To do this add it to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and rebuild the linker cache. Rebuilding the linker cache is done by executing `ldconfig` with superuser privileges.

Comment: i have fixed this problem, i remove purged all other xorg and nvidia drivers including nouveau by removing individually and also this sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

also i ran nvidia-xconfig after installation and i did the installation from recovery shell position